# How can I solve the error regarding the storages in Optuna?

Tags: sqlite, optuna, sqlite3-python

I am using optuna library for hyperparameter optimization. I am trying to create a study and a storage but i am getting the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/azureuser_rishi/JSSP/final/main_final.py", line 85, in <module>
    study = optuna.study.load_study(study_name=study_name, storage=storage_name)
  File "/home/azureuser_rishi/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/optuna/_convert_positional_args.py", line 63, in converter_wrapper
    return func(**kwargs)
  File "/home/azureuser_rishi/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/optuna/study/study.py", line 1253, in load_study
    return Study(study_name=study_name, storage=storage, sampler=sampler, pruner=pruner)
  File "/home/azureuser_rishi/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/optuna/study/study.py", line 77, in __init__
    storage = storages.get_storage(storage)
  File "/home/azureuser_rishi/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/optuna/storages/__init__.py", line 32, in get_storage
    return _CachedStorage(RDBStorage(storage))
  File "/home/azureuser_rishi/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/optuna/storages/_rdb/storage.py", line 225, in __init__
    self._version_manager.check_table_schema_compatibility()
  File "/home/azureuser_rishi/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/optuna/storages/_rdb/storage.py", line 1134, in check_table_schema_compatibility
    current_version = self.get_current_version()
  File "/home/azureuser_rishi/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/optuna/storages/_rdb/storage.py", line 1161, in get_current_version
    assert version is not None
AssertionError
```

I tried upgrading Optuna and sqlite3 libraries but the issue is not resolved. Does it also depend on the Python version since I am using 3.8 on my Azure VM. I hope someone can help me resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you share the minimal reproducible code when you ask a question?

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was resolved when I downgraded the SQLAlchemy package to 1.4.44.